# How do I use logcat in android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-logcat

Can any one please tell me how to use logcat? for example I get the error:

Null point exception at activity thread Java.2121. what does 2121 here refer to? Is it some line of code? How do I access it?

Comment: whats the full exception trace?

Comment: How about google? Took me 1 minute to find it: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=47172690&postcount=2   Please read the guide to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: so you want to remove ur execption??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not certain that the first line of the logcat itself shows the exact error. If you want to get the error from logcat in simplest way then try to find out your package name in that means for an example if your package name is com.test.firstapp then check for this in logcat...after that check for the statement it have then definitely you'll get the idea from that....Hope this'll help you :)

Answer (score 2):

Do not rely on the first line of the exception. Sometimes it happens from the middle when it started calling it. Check the last call to your activity class. That is the root of your problem.

Comment: okay. Also can you please tell me what does that 2121 mean in log cat?

Comment: It must be line number.

Comment: how do I search for that line in code?